# Check last messages

Tags: logs, make

I let a `make` command running last night when connected via SSH to a remote machine. Then had to close that SSH session, letting `make` run.

How can I check the last printed messages on the console (to know if no error was issued)?

Comment: How did you let the process continue running after disconnection? Using `nohup` `disown`? Or inside a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`? In the latter case, the output could be recoverable by just browsing the terminal buffer history, depending on the max buffer limit.

Comment: So after closing the SSH session the make command "closes" whit it. Thought the command would keep running =\ Thanks!

Comment: if you used nohup without i/o redirection look in nohup.out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would recommend is to prepeare in advance, and run the command as follows:

`nohup make install >> /var/log/messages &`

or, another option, install screen. Before running the command create a new screen with `screen` command.
When coming back, type `screen -r`, or `screen -r <screenid>` if you have several screens opened to log back in to the session and see all messages printed.

Both of these commands require that you run the commands differently and I don't think they can help you if you already run the command as you did and wish to see its results now.